# ExpressJS SSL on one domain only

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using ExpressJS. My `app` is a `https` server which also contains a vhost.

```
app.use(express.vhost('api.example.com', require('./lib/subdomains/api').app));
```

Because my SSL certificate is for the root domain only, my `api.example.com` domain now fails to load the routes it's been given.

How can I only use SSL on my root domain and not on my other? I need to be able to share the app configuration between the domains, but not the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh. I hadn't changed my `NODE_ENV` so the vhost was setup incorrectly in the live environment.